# Parallelize[Mapindexed[]], level={-1}? Sal Mangano's 《Cookbook》

Tags: parallelization, map

It is easy to **Parallelize[]** Map[] & MapIndexed[], as having been shown in MMA9 Help for ParallelMap[] and Parallelize[].

For [MapIndexed[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html), the default **levelspec** is {1}. However there are many cases when we need mapping to deeper levels such as {-1}, for example with image data (2D array). I have tried Parallelize[] and found it FAILED and switched to **sequential evaluation** whenever **levelspec** is explicitly specified, actually even when **levelspec={1}** !

[image]

In page 652 of Sal Mangano's [*Mathematica Cookbook*](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&q=mapindexed#v=snippet&q=mapindexed&f=true), he seems to have written functions which

1. use Parallelize[] on MapIndexed[]
2. able to specify **levelSpec**

[image]

I don't know how he achieved that, and his example was not detailed enough to see the intended effect. I actually suspect that: with the default levelspec={1}, Parallelize[] could conveniently distribute the elements on the first level of the list across different kernels (like **breadth-first search** on level 1, using a **queue** in C); however if we need to go deeper with MapIndexed[]'s **depth-first** (see [help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html)) search, then the parallel implementation would be very difficult.

So is it true that **Parallelize[Mapindexed[]]** only works with default/implicit levelSpec={1}, not others?

Is Mr. Sal Mangano on this forum? Could he also comment?

Comment: [Sal Mangano](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/104/sal-mangano) is in this forum.

Comment: @halirutan But he hasn't been visiting us for a while

Comment: @halirutan Is is possible to send forum message (like private message/mail) on other forums? Or can I find his email in the profile (didn't succeed)?

Comment: No, *you* cannot send any message. As you can see from his profile, he was not on SE since March 2012. Se even if you could send some kind of forum message, he wouldn't receive it because it is very unlikely that he has email notification turned on. I'm not sure how inappropriate it would be if you mail him directly, point him to the question and ask him for his opinion. But maybe the question will be answered by other users and you won't even need him *personally*.

Comment: @JimmyLin You can find information on his [website](http://mathematicacookbook.com/), for example  he is active on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/salmangano). I don't know how he feels about being contacted about this though.

Comment: @halirutan I think the question is answered here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the book that implementation is meant for users who use *Mathematica* v. 7 and don't have access to `ParallelMap`. It would be very odd if a function meant to substitute another does not accept the same arguments. I would say that this is the reason that levelspec is included. I also note that in the documentation for `ParallelMap`, the function it is meant to replace, it says:

> Parallelize[Map[f,expr]] is equivalent to ParallelMap[f,expr].

it also says

> ParallelMap uses the same level specifications as Map. Not all level
>   specifications can be parallelized.

So really, the function as implemented in the book does exactly what it is supposed to. It is the best you can do for v. 7 and might even be as good as `ParallelMap` in version 9.

(My answer to your question is not to confirm or deny what levelspecs it works for, but it doesn't work for all and it doesn't for more levelspecs than `ParallelMap`.)

Comment: I believe so, "Not all level specifications can be parallelized."